# Java - Executing two corrosponding for loops at same time

Tags: java, for-loop

I have two for loops written in java below. The first one grabs all the titles of news articles on a website, and the second one grabs all the links of the same new articles on the same website.

How do I make it so that when the first loop executes once, the second loop executes once, and then the first loop executes a second time, and the second one executes a second time, etc. I would really appreciate your help, thanks.

```
for( org.jsoup.nodes.Element element : elements1 ){

   sendMessageRequest.setText(element.text());


   sendMessage(sendMessageRequest);
   System.out.print("sent message");
}

for( org.jsoup.nodes.Element element : elements2 ) {

   sendMessageRequest.setText(element.text());


   sendMessage(sendMessageRequest);
   System.out.print("sent message");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `elements1` and `elements2` are some kind of [`Iterable<Element>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), e.g. [`List<Element>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

First, remember that `for (Element element : elements1)` is just syntactic sugar for:

```
Iterator<Element> iter = elements1.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Element element = iter.next();
    // code here
}
```

<sup>Except that you don't have access to the [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).</sup>

So, if you want to iterate two different `Iterable` objects, do so the old-fashioned way:

```
Iterator<Element> iter1 = elements1.iterator();
Iterator<Element> iter2 = elements2.iterator();
while (iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext()) {
    Element element1 = iter1.next();
    Element element2 = iter2.next();
    // code here
}
```

If the two `Iterable` objects are not the same length, the loop will only iterate until the shorter one has been exhausted. Extra elements in the other one will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If `elements1` and `elements2` are guaranteed to have the same length, just iterate through them into one loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements1.length; i++) {
    processMessageRequest(elements1[i]);
    processMessageRequest(elements2[i]);
}
```

Using a new method `processMessageRequest` to make your code more DRY:

```
private void processMessageRequest(Element e) {
    sendMessageRequest.setText(e.text());
    sendMessage(sendMessageRequest);
    System.out.println("sent message");
}
```

I'm not sure what the scope of `sendMessageRequest` is... but with some tweaking this way could work.

Comment: Assuming they are arrays, not `Collection` objects.

Comment: Very true. Now that I think about it `org.jsoup.Elements` most likely implements a `Collection` interface. I'll +1 your answer.